# Can not read my json file by using json package

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am new to python3 and try to read my josn file froma google cloud storage bucket as follow:

```
try:
    content=#downlaod from blob
    print(content)
    json_application_properties=json.loads(str(content))
except Exception as ex:
```

my json file looks like below:

```
{
    "application": {
        "project_id": "fiery-bay-224704"
    },
    "ingestion": {
        "fileingestion_mappings": {
            "id":"small-files",
            "input_directory": "gs://small-files/*",
            "staging_directory": "gs://small-files/staging",
            "kafka_topic": "kafkatopic-small-files",
            "big_query_table_name": "bigquery-small-files"
        },
         "fileingestion_mappings": {
            "id":"big-files",
            "input_directory": "gs://small-files/*",
            "staging_directory": "gs://small-files/staging",
            "kafka_topic": "kafkatopic-small-files",
            "big_query_table_name": "bigquery-small-files"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get exception while reading it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    gcs_object_insert()
  File "main.py", line 17, in gcs_object_insert
    json_application_properties=json.loads(str(content))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Can some one point me why this error happenning and why my JSON file is invalid

te print contet is as follow:

```
b'{\r\n\t"application": {\r\n\t\t"project_id": "fiery-bay-224704"\r\n\t},\r\n\t"ingestion": {\r\n\t\t"fileingestion_mappings": {\r\n\t\t    "id":"small-files",\r\n\t\t\t"input_directory": "gs://small-files/*",\r\n\t\t\t"staging_directory": "gs://small-files/staging",\r\n\t\t\t"kafka_topic": "kafkatopic-small-files",\r\n\t\t\t"big_query_table_name": "bigquery-small-files"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t "fileingestion_mappings": {\r\n\t\t    "id":"big-files",\r\n\t\t\t"input_directory": "gs://small-files/*",\r\n\t\t\t"staging_directory": "gs://small-files/staging",\r\n\t\t\t"kafka_topic": "kafkatopic-small-files",\r\n\t\t\t"big_query_table_name": "bigquery-small-files"\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t}\r\n}'
```

Comment: works for me... what does the print(content) print out? btw your json is actually invalid - the key fileingestion_mappings is duplicated, but that is not the issue - json package will just use one of them

Comment: I editted my question and I need to read both fileingestion_mappings as they have different IDs.

Comment: you cant have 2 keys of the same name - one will be lost, it is not valid json - you would have to parse it yourselves or make the source return them under different keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` you load is a bytes object - it cannot be converted into string without specifying the encoding

i.e.

```
bytes_object = b'this is bytes object'
print(str(bytes_object))
>>> b'this is bytes object'
```

the json parser sees the beginning 'b' instead of expected '{'

instead of using `str(something)` conversion, on byte object use `.decode(formatting)` ( see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode )

so in your case

```
json_application_properties=json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
```